# Spring injecting implementation bean

Tags: java, spring, config

I have the following snippet from a conf spring file:

```
<bean id="taskletStep" abstract="true" class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hello" class="com.techavalanche.batch.PrintTasklet">
        <property name="message" value="Hello"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="world" class="com.techavalanche.batch.PrintTasklet">
        <property name="message" value=" World!"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySimpleJob" class="org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob">
        <property name="name" value="mySimpleJob" />
        <property name="steps">
            <list>
                <bean parent="taskletStep">
                    <property name="tasklet" ref="hello"/>
                </bean>

                <bean parent="taskletStep">
                    <property name="tasklet" ref="world"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
```

To me it is not very clear the following bit:

```
<bean parent="taskletStep">
                    <property name="tasklet" ref="hello"/>
                </bean>
```

taskletStep it is an interface and does not have any property. However the code works fine, it seems that the bean with ID "hello" gets injected. Therefore I am asking, is this the standard way from the config file to inject a bean implementation (id: **hello**) to an interface bean (id: **taskletStep**)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tasklet step in Spring Batch Job. What you are doing is perfectly fine. Alternatively, you can also do something like this:

```
<job id="mySimpleJob">
    <step id="step1">
        <tasklet ref="hello"/>
    </step>

    <step id="step2">
        <tasklet ref="world"/>
    </step>
</job>
```

Here is a complete reference:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/htmlsingle/

Comment: Ok, So injecting a bean in an interface, in this case a TaskletStep, it is possible by using <property> tag in the interface? Does not make much sense to me because an interface has no property. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: I know what you mean. It made no sense to me either when I first started using it. Link: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/1.0.x/spring-batch-docs/reference/html/execution.html

Comment: @userr2004685 what about the use of next  in the steps' listing?  ie: `<job id="footballJob">
    <step id="playerload" next="gameLoad"/>
    <step id="gameLoad" next="playerSummarization"/>
    <step id="playerSummarization"/>
</job>` is it actually needed specifying the next? I have never seen it around before.

Comment: @Rollerball It is used to specify the next step to be executed. I have never used it though.

Comment: @userr2004685 yhea I mean.. would make sense only if you have a list of steps and from 1 you want to jump to 3 or any other step.. otherwise it iterates one by one sequentially..